# Custom Group in Crystal Report

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

Hi i need to prepare a report in Crystal report and i need your help as i am 
 new in crystal report.

scenario is below.

i have a SqlServer view like this:

ID:   Time Slot:      Duration:
  1     09:00-09:30         30
  2     09:30-10:00         30
  3     10:00-10:30         30
  4     10:30-11:00         30 
  5     10:30-11:00         30

i need output like this:

GROUP ONE: (CUSTOM GROUP NAME IN CRYSTAL REPORT)

ID:    TimeSlot    Duration
 1     09:00-09:30         30
 2     09:30-10:00         30
_______________________________
           sum of duration(60)

Group Two
ID:    TimeSlot    Duration
 3     10:00-10:30         30
 4     10:30-11:00         30
5     10:30-11:00          30 (note it can be duplicate) 
______________________________
      (sum of Duration) (90)

Please suggest solution in crystal report or even in sql server View.....
thanks in advance....

Comment: What is the definition of your group?? Is the result always the same? What if there is another row 
with ID: 6, TimeSlot: 09.30-10.00, Duration:30??

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 sub reports in one sub report limit the grouping to 1 and 2 and in second limit to other IDs